# Как запустить AVD на Ubuntu?

Tags: java, android, ubuntu, xubuntu

Установил я Ubuntu 16.4.2
После установил Android Studio. Запустил AVD. Скачал API 21 Без Google apis.

Запускаю AVD Идет запуск и все. В консоли пусто. Никакой реакции нет. Ни окно AVD не запустилось. Ни какой загрузки короче тишина. Попробовал так пару десятков раз.

Пробовал скачать Google apis 21 тишина. Скачал 22 тишина. API 25 тишина.

Как запустить AVD на Ubuntu?

Процессор у меня AMD

Comment: Android Emulator установили? В SDK Manager на второй вкладке(SDK Tools)

Comment: Да установил. Все равно не работает